# What constrains how much a divider can move in JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jsplitpane

Have an application that uses a [`JSplitPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) to divide a frame into top and bottom. I am having a problem that the divider only allows limited movement, preventing the bottom pane from being as large as I would like, and it is worse with some look and feels.

[image]

I have:

```
splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.0f);
```

The bottom pane should get priority on space. but it doesn't.

After frame is visible I get the values of `min` and `max` divider location, and this seems to match how much I can move the divider, but what decides these values?

```
ScreenLayout.getInstanceOf().getLayout().getMaximumDividerLocation());
ScreenLayout.getInstanceOf().getLayout().getDividerLocation()
```

It is better on Windows than MacOS, and on MacOS it works in a limited way with the standard Aqua Look and feel, but can only make smaller with FlatLaf look and feel

Comment: It looks like "…the minimum size of the `Components` is used…"

Comment: thanks setting     ScreenLayout.getInstanceOf().getLayout().getTopComponent().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0)); does resolve the issue, but im going to do some digging to see what is causing minimum size to be set to what it is (height 501)

Comment: @CatalinaIsland note in the screenshot the top component is a JTabbedPane containig 9 tabs, I retrieved the minimum size for one of  the  tabs (a JScollPane) and it minimum height was fine, but the minimum height of JTabbedPane seems to be the sum of all the tabs, so the more tabs you have the larger the minimum height of the JTabbedPane, surely a bug !

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug that JTabbedPane sets its minimum size based on summing up all the tabs height if they are JScrollPane, so the more tabs added the larger the minimum height of JTabbedPane, there doesn't seem to be an issue if add JTable directly to a JTabbedPane rather than a JTable wrapped in a JScrollPane but that is no use to me.

```
import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;
import java.io.File;

public class TabbedPaneTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            JTable t1 = new JTable(5,5);
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(tabbedPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(t1.getMinimumSize());
            System.out.println("scroll 1:"+tabbedPane.getComponentAt(0).getMinimumSize());
            System.out.println("TaBbedPane 1:"+tabbedPane.getMinimumSize());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            JTable t1 = new JTable(5,5);
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));
            tabbedPane.addTab("", new JScrollPane(t1));

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(tabbedPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(t1.getMinimumSize());
            System.out.println("Scroll 1"+ tabbedPane.getComponentAt(0).getMinimumSize());
            System.out.println("Tabbed Pane 2"+tabbedPane.getMinimumSize());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=75,height=80]
scroll 1:java.awt.Dimension[width=22,height=26]
TaBbedPane 1:java.awt.Dimension[width=27,height=54]
java.awt.Dimension[width=75,height=80]
Scroll 1java.awt.Dimension[width=22,height=22]
Tabbed Pane 2java.awt.Dimension[width=27,height=168]
```

If after creating JTabbedPane with tabs I hardcode `setMinimumSize`() the split pane works okay.

Comment: What happens if you construct the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?